# How to get the current directory in a C program?

Tags: c, unix, working-directory

I'm making a C program where I need to get the directory that the program is started from.  This program is written for UNIX computers. I've been looking at `opendir()` and `telldir()`, but `telldir()` returns a `off_t (long int)`, so it really doesn't help me.

How can I get the current path in a string (char array)?

Answer (score 390, accepted):

Have you had a look at [`getcwd()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html)?

```
#include <unistd.h>
char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);
```

Simple example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>

int main() {
   char cwd[PATH_MAX];
   if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
       printf("Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
   } else {
       perror("getcwd() error");
       return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Picking the pickiest of nits, <errno.h> seems unnecessary, and the program reports success even on failure via its exit status.  Otherwise, a nice example.

Comment: Oh, and is it more conventional to use printf(...) in place of fprintf(stdout, ...)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's not the pickiest of nits. This is: `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: I would use PATH_MAX from limits.h, instead of magic number if ~4KB on stack is not an issue.

Comment: Still not there, your buffer should also accommodate for the string-termination byte/null, therefore the correct one is ```char cwd[PATH_MAX+1]```. Or if you can't be bothered with buffers just ```char *buf=getcwd(NULL,0);``` and when you are done ```free(buf)``` (as of POSIX.1-2001)

Comment: If I run the program from a `cron` this function will not return the directory of the program as expected.

Comment: @bliako But still not there. [`PATH_MAX` is not necessarily defined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html#tag_13_23_03_02): "A definition of one of the symbolic constants in the following list shall be omitted from the `<limits.h>` header on specific implementations where the corresponding value is equal to or greater than the stated minimum, but where the value can vary depending on the file to which it is applied. The actual value supported for a specific pathname shall be provided by the `pathconf()` function."

Comment: @Andrew Henle, that's why I offered the PATH_MAX-less solution.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sizeof cwd` instead of `sizeof(cwd)` ?

Comment: In Linux (glibc), `get_current_dir_name()` is a bit more convenient (does its own malloc). I wanted to get just the directory name, not the entire path, so I did `basename(get_current_dir_name())`.

Comment: @Liam If `get_current_dir_name()` does its own `malloc()`, `basename(get_current_dir_name())` is an unfixable memory leak.

Answer (score 60):

Look up the man page for `getcwd`.

Comment: @angad teach a man to fish but atleast show him path to the lake/sea/ocean :)

Comment: people recommending man to people trying to use the vastly superior search method google are out of touch.

Comment: Code snippet: `man 3 getcwd`. Jokes aside, don't be anarchonistic, this post is from '08, SO conventions were different.

Comment: @gbtimmon google is a search engine, it is not analogous to man page. It is eventually going to point to the man page.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya The correct Google term is "How to get cwd in C++". If that gets a man page, the term changes to "How to get cwd in C++ Stack Overflow".

Answer (score 33):

Although the question is tagged Unix, people also get to visit it when their target platform is Windows, and the answer for Windows is the [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
DWORD WINAPI GetCurrentDirectory(
  _In_  DWORD  nBufferLength,
  _Out_ LPTSTR lpBuffer
);
```

These answers apply to both C and C++ code.

<sup>Link suggested by [user4581301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4581301/user4581301) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487046/getting-the-output-of-cd-or-simply-getting-the-current-directory#comment50938605_31487046) to another question, and verified as the current top choice with a Google search 'site:microsoft.com getcurrentdirectory'.</sup>

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that this is c... is it? LPTSTR?

Comment: @floydheld — It _is_ C but it is using Microsoft Windows type names.  Many of those are all upper-case letters (and numbers and underscores), in contrast to most other systems where the types are all lower-case instead (with some exceptions: `FILE` and `DIR` spring to mind in POSIX systems).

Comment: You're providing wrong answer because the question say **for UNIX computers**

Comment: Even if the question asks for UNIX, this is probably the top answer on Google and is clearly still useful to misguided visitors.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* defines FILENAME_MAX */
//#define WINDOWS  /* uncomment this line to use it for windows.*/
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <direct.h>
#define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#define GetCurrentDir getcwd
#endif

int main(){
  char buff[FILENAME_MAX];
  GetCurrentDir( buff, FILENAME_MAX );
  printf("Current working dir: %s\n", buff);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use pre_defined macros for detecting OS like #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__WINDOWS__)

Comment: If the code in [HaseeB Mir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6219626/haseeb-mir)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program/31487237#comment93103084_47877476) was enclosed in back-quotes, I believe it would look like: `#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__WINDOWS__)`.  The bold __WINDOWS__ strongly hints at double-underscores before and after 'WINDOWS'.  However, looking at some corporate code that caters to Windows (as well as Unix) builds, I find `#if defined(_WINDOWS) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)` — YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

To get current directory (where you execute your target program), you can use the following example code, which works for both Visual Studio and Linux/MacOS(gcc/clang), both C and C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <direct.h>
#define getcwd _getcwd
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

int main() {
    char* buffer;

    if( (buffer=getcwd(NULL, 0)) == NULL) {
        perror("failed to get current directory\n");
    } else {
        printf("%s \nLength: %zu\n", buffer, strlen(buffer));
        free(buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `getcwd(3)` is also available in Microsoft's libc: [getcwd(3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y(v=vs.90).aspx), and works the same way you'd expect.

Must link with `-loldnames` (oldnames.lib, which is done automatically in most cases), or use `_getcwd()`. The unprefixed version is unavailable under Windows RT.

Answer (score 1):

Use    **getcwd**

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* defines FILENAME_MAX */
//#define WINDOWS  /* uncomment this line to use it for windows.*/
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <direct.h>
#define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#define GetCurrentDir getcwd
#endif

int main(){
  char buff[FILENAME_MAX];
  GetCurrentDir( buff, FILENAME_MAX );
  printf("Current working dir: %s\n", buff);
  return 1;
}
```

OR

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>

main() {
char *buf;
buf=(char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
getcwd(buf,100);
printf("\n %s \n",buf);
}
```

Comment: Your second example leaks memory. I'm aware that the OS will clear all memory allocate for the process anyway in this case but think about the people that come will copy the code without paying attention this will potentially cause deep problems for them later.