# How to get Current Directory?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to create a file in the current directory (where the executable is running).

My code:

```
LPTSTR NPath = NULL;
DWORD a = GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,NPath);
HANDLE hNewFile = CreateFile(NPath,GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
```

I get exception at `GetCurrentDirectory()`.

Why am I getting an exception?

Comment: #include <unistd.h>
   char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the directory that a program is running from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/how-do-i-get-the-directory-that-a-program-is-running-from)

Comment: Please NOTE: current directory is not always the directory that the exe is in.      
(e.g. c:\users\me> \dir1\dir2\runme.exe  here you are in c:\users\me and running exe from \dir1\dir2\).

Comment: NULL pointer - you'll get an Access violation

Comment: no @hfrmobile, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory

Comment: @Sergei Krivonos: The documentation says that I am right :o)

Comment: no @hfrmobile, it says "To determine the required buffer size, set this parameter to NULL and the nBufferLength parameter to 0." so this causes no access violation.

Comment: You have to set **both** parameters to zero!!!

"To determine the required buffer size, set this parameter to NULL and the nBufferLength parameter to 0."

If *nBufferLength* is > 0 and buffer point NULL --> possible access violation

Comment: likely seg fault because of null pointer - it is not pointing to any memory and so dereferencing it will likely cause a crash (which is what takes place inside the function)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I would recommend reading a book on C++ before you go any further, as it would be helpful to get a firmer footing. [Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/) by Koenig and Moo is excellent.

To get the executable path use [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
```

Here's a C++ function that gets the directory without the file name:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::wstring ExePath() {
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
    std::wstring::size_type pos = std::wstring(buffer).find_last_of(L"\\/");
    return std::wstring(buffer).substr(0, pos);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "my directory is " << ExePath() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: NB that you may need to use a wide char, like wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH]; these days...

Comment: Or `GetModuleFileNameA`

Comment: To reiterate over what @Mikhail said, you would use `GetModuleFileNameA` for code which utilizes a multi-byte character set, and `GetModuleFileNameW` for unicode. `GetModuleFileName` (without the `A` or `W`) is actually an alias for whichever character set your project is set to use, which is how most Win32 API methods which utilize strings are set up. So if you have a unicode project, and your strings are is also unicode, then you would only have to call `GetModuleFileName`. The same applies if your project is multi-byte and uses multi-byte strings.

Comment: I don't like the parameter or the `find_last_of()` method, isn't there some constant which defines the separator in directory names, like ".../.../..." or "...\...\..."?

Comment: this is windows only

Comment: I am trying to run this on Windows 10 using Visual Studio Code and I get `'wstring' does not name a type; did you mean 'wctrans'?`

Comment: This is only useful if your current directory is where your executable is. Those don't always match, especially with visual studio and cmake...

Comment: @Jorje12 Did you compiled as C++ code?

Answer (score 97):

The question is not clear whether the current working directory is wanted or the path of the directory containing the executable.

Most answers seem to answer the latter.

But for the former, and for the second part of the question of creating the file, the C++17 standard now incorporates the `filesystem` library which simplifies this a lot:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

std::filesystem::path cwd = std::filesystem::current_path() / "filename.txt";
std::ofstream file(cwd.string());
file.close();
```

This fetches the current working directory, adds the filename to the path and creates an empty file. Note that the path object takes care of os dependent path handling, so `cwd.string()` returns an os dependent path string. Neato.

Comment: How can we use <filesystem> library to get the path of the directory containing the executable please?

Comment: afaik the <filesystem> does not have a straightforward way to do that. Sorry. Please see the other answers for that partof the question.

Comment: The subject of the question is "How to get Current Directory?"

Answer (score 52):

`GetCurrentDirectory` does not allocate space for the result, it's up to you to do that.

```
TCHAR NPath[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, NPath);
```

Also, take a look at [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library if you want to do this the C++ way.

Comment: Hmm,NPath points to another directory,how do I make it show the directory where the executable is placed in?

Comment: The current directory is not the same as the executable's directory, even under C# and Delphi. Perhaps you could make your question clearer?

Comment: John, that's a little more involved and can't be simply answered in a comment. Perhaps you should follow Neil's advice (both of them).

Answer (score 24):

An easy way to do this is:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    std::cout << argv[0]; 
    std::cin.get();
}
```

`argv[]` is pretty much an array containing arguments you ran the .exe with, but the first one is always a path to the executable. If I build this the console shows:
`C:\Users\Ulisse\source\repos\altcmd\Debug\currentdir.exe`

Comment: Best answer for its simplicity.

Comment: Note: This won't be updated as the program runs though, so it only tells where the program is run from not necessarily the current working directory.

Comment: `GetCurrentDirectory` returns current directory of process, i.e the working directory. `argv[0]` is the path of executable file. One different is that the working directory can be changed during the life-cycle of a process while `argv[0]` can not be changed.

Answer (score 14):

IMHO here are some improvements to [anon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/875264/184528).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string GetExeFileName()
{
  char buffer[MAX_PATH];
  GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
  return std::string(buffer);
}

std::string GetExePath() 
{
  std::string f = GetExeFileName();
  return f.substr(0, f.find_last_of( "\\/" ));
}
```

Comment: This is actually different. YOu don't provide the directory path, you provide the path of the file, including the file.

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

std::string current_working_directory()
{
    char* cwd = _getcwd( 0, 0 ) ; // **** microsoft specific ****
    std::string working_directory(cwd) ;
    std::free(cwd) ;
    return working_directory ;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "i am now in " << current_working_directory() << endl;
}
```

I failed to use GetModuleFileName correctly. I found this work very well.
just tested on Windows, not yet try on Linux :)

Answer (score 6):

Please don't forget to initialize your buffers to *something* before utilizing them. And just as important, give your string buffers space for the ending null

```
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH+1] = L"";
DWORD len = GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, path);
```

[Reference](http://books.google.ca/books?id=mmjVIC6WolgC&pg=PT128&lpg=PT128&dq=alexandrescu+initialize+variables&source=bl&ots=ccQnLOhLVc&sig=ZSIyxrBMrp1kkC-iFNPwWx-O-m4&hl=en&ei=6izZTr3YHIThiAL7-4HqDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 5):

```
WCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {0};
GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);
PathRemoveFileSpec(path);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should provide a valid buffer placeholder.
that is:

```
TCHAR s[100];
DWORD a = GetCurrentDirectory(100, s);
```

Answer (score 3):

GetCurrentDirectory() gets the current directory which is where the exe is invoked *from*. To get the location of the exe, use GetModuleFileName(NULL ...). <strike>if you have the handle to the exe, or you can derive it from GetCommandLine() if you don't.</strike>

As Mr. Butterworth points out, you don't need a handle.

Comment: Actually, you don't need a real handle - a NULL handle gets the executable file name, with path.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

// The directory path returned by native GetCurrentDirectory() no end backslash
string getCurrentDirectoryOnWindows()
{
    const unsigned long maxDir = 260;
    char currentDir[maxDir];
    GetCurrentDirectory(maxDir, currentDir);
    return string(currentDir);
}
```

Comment: `currentDir` - An argument of type `"char *"` is incompatible with a parameter of type `"LPWSTR"` (Unicode encoding)

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the filename from `GetModuleFileName()` with more elegant way:

```
TCHAR fullPath[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR driveLetter[3];
TCHAR directory[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR FinalPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, fullPath, MAX_PATH);
_splitpath(fullPath, driveLetter, directory, NULL, NULL);
sprintf(FinalPath, "%s%s",driveLetter, directory);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Why does nobody here consider using this simple code?

```
TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

GetModuleFileName(NULL, szDir, MAX_PATH);
szDir[std::string(szDir).find_last_of("\\/")] = 0;
```

or even simpler

```
TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
TCHAR* szEnd = nullptr;
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szDir, MAX_PATH);
szEnd = _tcsrchr(szDir, '\\');
*szEnd = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, that the easiest way to locate the current directory is to cut it from command line args.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::string cur_dir(argv[0]);
  int pos = cur_dir.find_last_of("/\\");

  std::cout << "path: " << cur_dir.substr(0, pos) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "file: " << cur_dir.substr(pos+1) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You may know that every program gets its executable name as first command line argument. So you can use this.

Comment: Very useful for mac as well unlike other answers that I had an issue with. Also liked that you parsed the string to get the directory. thanks - up voted

Comment: This code won't give the current directory; it will give the directory where the executable file is found (on some platforms).

Comment: This won't give the CWD. It will give the path used to execute the binary. If I executed the following: `$ ./prog`, `argv[0]` would be `"./prog`

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Present working directory is not the same as directory where the executable resides. As Ciro has pointed out already.

Answer (score 1):

I simply use getcwd() method for that purpose in Windows, and it works pretty well. The code portion is like following:

```
#include <direct.h>

// ...

char cwd[256];
getcwd(cwd, 256);
std::string cwd_str = std::string(cwd);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on your c++ version, try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
// code for C++17 and later
#include <filesystem>
std::string cwd() { return std::filesystem::current_path(); }

#else
// code for earlier versions of c++
#include <unistd.h>
std::string cwd() {
    char buffer[FILENAME_MAX];
    if (getcwd(buffer, FILENAME_MAX) != nullptr) {
        return {buffer};
    }
    return "";
}
#endif


int main() {
    std::cout << cwd();
}
```

What's more we can get this from linux procfs, it's works in any language:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

// ONLY WORKING IN UNIX-LIKE SYSTEMS SUCH AS LINUX
int main() {
    char cwd[PATH_MAX];
    ssize_t size = readlink("/proc/self/cwd", cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    if (size != -1) {
        cwd[size] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the string
        std::cout << "current working directory: " << cwd << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "failed to read cwd" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is asking for Windows, not Linux!

Answer (score 0):

Code snippets from my CAE project with unicode development environment:

```
/// @brief Gets current module file path. 
std::string getModuleFilePath() {
    TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
    CT2CA pszPath(buffer);
    std::string path(pszPath);
    std::string::size_type pos = path.find_last_of("\\/");
    return path.substr( 0, pos);
}
```

Just use the templete **CA2CAEX** or **CA2AEX** which calls the internal API **::MultiByteToWideChar** or **::WideCharToMultiByte**。

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Poco](https://pocoproject.org/) library, it's a one liner and it should work on all platforms I think.

```
Poco::Path::current()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use std, you can use this code:

```
char * ExePath() 
{
   static char buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
   GetModuleFileName( NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH );
   char * LastSlash = strrchr(buffer, '\\');
   if(LastSlash == NULL)
        LastSlash = strrchr(buffer, '/');
    
   buffer[LastSlash-buffer] = 0;
   return buffer;
}
```

Comment: The question is asking about getting the **current** directory, not the execute path.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) says...

> `[out] lpBuffer`
>
> A pointer to the buffer that receives the current directory string.
> This null-terminated string specifies the absolute path to the current
> directory.
>
> To determine the required buffer size, set this parameter to **NULL** and
> the *nBufferLength* parameter to 0.

You're getting the required buffer size, not the path (`NPath` is NULL) and you're passing `MAX_PATH` to *nBufferLength*.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Null_pointer_constant) says...

> C++11 corrects this by introducing a new **keyword** to serve as a
> distinguished null pointer constant: nullptr. It is of **type nullptr_t**,
> which is implicitly convertible and comparable to any pointer type or
> pointer-to-member type. It is not implicitly convertible or comparable
> to integral types, except for bool.

There's no way to deference a `nullptr` and `NULL` (make an access violation exception).

The code should be this:

```
LPTSTR NewPath;
DWORD a = GetCurrentDirectory(0, NULL);
NewPath = new TCHAR[a];
GetCurrentDirectory(a, NPath);
HANDLE hNewFile = CreateFile(NewPath, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Answer (score -1):

To find the directory where your executable is, you can use:

```
TCHAR szFilePath[_MAX_PATH];
::GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFilePath, _MAX_PATH);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String^ exePath = Application::ExecutablePath;<br>
MessageBox::Show(exePath);
```

Comment: The question doesn't say it's managed or not, so default it's unmanaged, don't post C++ managed code!

Answer (score -3):

On a give Windows C++ IDE I went crude and it was simple, reliable, but slow:

```
system( "cd" );
```

Comment: Better avoid the impression of belittling other answers.

Comment: Please make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute beyond existing answers, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71663339/7733418

Answer (score -4):

In Windows console, you can use the system command CD (Current Directory):

```
std::cout << "Current Directory = ";
system("cd"); // to see the current executable directory
```

Comment: How storing to a variable?