# MFC: GetCurrentDirectory function

Tags: mfc

I know that GetCurrentDirectory() and SetCurrentDirectory() functions exist on the MFC framework, but I don't have a CFtpConnection object in my application. I have a simple CWinApp-derived class, and I would like to retrieve its working directory upon program startup. What's the easiest method to achieve this goal? Thanks in advance for the advices.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364934(VS.85).aspx ... nothing to do with whether or not you have a CFtpConnection object.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875249/how-to-get-current-directory

Comment: Under normal circumstances the working folder is going to be found in the user application data folder and there is a special API to get special folder locations. So, you have to decide how you are managing where the working folder will be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

GetCurrentDirectory is a simple Win32 API function, so just call it like this:

```
TCHAR currentDir[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory( MAX_PATH, currentDir );
```

Comment: There is the same code, but using CString class (don't forget to call `ReleaseBuffer()` for your `CString` object):
`CString curDir;
GetCurrentDirectory( MAX_PATH, curDir.GetBufferSetLength(MAX_PATH));
curDir.ReleaseBuffer();`

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are trying to get the directory where your .exe file is located instead of the current directory. This directory can be different from the current directory.

```
    TCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
    memset(buff, 0, MAX_PATH);
    ::GetModuleFileName(NULL,buff,sizeof(buff));    
    CString strFolder = buff;
    strFolder = strFolder.Left(strFolder.ReverseFind(_T('\\'))+1);
```

Comment: The path of the exe (or dll) is not necessarily the current directory. As soon as this is not the case any more you will run into problems if you use this solution.

Comment: What you are talking about? this solution is just to avoid the case which current directory is different from the directory the exe file is. The question changed from he original asked.