# Output file to specific folder C++ Windows 7

Tags: c++, file-io, save

I am using C++ and trying to output a file to a specific place, a folder with a specified name in the same directory as the executable. Couldn't find a great resource on an easy way to do this but I know it must be possible.

My example. I am saving a log file and instead of having it save to the same directory as the executable, it saves to /logs/

Thank you for your time!

Edit: I used mkdir to create a folder but how do I output to that folder. Is mkdir even a good thing to be using? I want to learn the best way to do this, not necessarily the easiest.

Comment: Assuming that you are using mkdir () function call (by including sys/stat.h), and not a system ("mkdir"), your usage of mkdir() is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()  {
    std::ofstream of( "C:\\mydir\\somewhere\\log.txt" );
    of << "hello\n";
}
```

will write "hello" to the file log.txt in the directory c:\mydir\somewhere, assuming the directory exists. And yes, mkdir is the right function to use. If you don't want to hardcode the path, you can find the path & name of the executable with [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and then create the path programatically from that - see [How to get Current Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875249/how-to-get-current-directory) for an example.

Comment: As a sidenote, you could also use *nix-style slash, ie "C:/mydir/somewhere/log.txt", that results in a more portable code.

Comment: Can you do a relative file path, like - \\dirname\\log.txt, or whatever?