# Benchmarking on the 2006 Middlebury Stereo Dataset

Tags: c++, computer-vision

my problem is the following:
I have developed a superpixel segmentation algorithm and i want to test how the superpixel behave in stereo imagery. For this i use the Middlebury Stereo Dataset 2006 (http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/scenes2006/),  right now i load one pair of images segment them and then compute my metrics (basically a fancy IOU) on it. This now works properly and now i want to extend it that it not only uses one pair of stereo images but the whole dataset.

Programming language is C++.

Here lies the problem:
How would i efficiently load all images? Because the pairs are all in independent folders (for the structure of the folder see below).

My idea would be to have a list of paths to the folders and then import all images from one folder, compute everything and then load the next folder.
How would i do that?

> Structure of each stereo pair is like that:
>
> ```
> Folder with the name of the item (like cat, wood, baby, ...)
>     disp1.png
>     disp5.png
>     view1.png
>     view5.png
> ```

Right now at the start of the my program i load images like that:

```
String pathImageLeft = "/Users/Stereo/Left/view1.png";
String pathImageRight = "/Users/Stereo/Right/view5.png";
String pathDisparityLeft = "/Users/Stereo/DisparityMap/disp1.png";
String pathDisparityRight = "/Users/Stereo/DisparityMap/disp5.png";
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Is your question about accessing directories or about accessing the URL? After having written an answer I'm not quite sure anymore. (So, consider it as pre-liminary.)

Comment: It's about accessing them as directories, i have downloaded them all manually, and thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood OP's question right, it can be reduced to

*How can I access directories?*

From C++17, there is a [Filesystem libary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) available which provides access to directories in a portable way.

Namely, it provides a [`std::filesystem::directory_entry`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_entry) which

> Represents a directory entry. The object stores a path as a member and may also store additional file attributes (hard link count, status, symlink status file size, and last write time) during directory iteration.

and a [`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator)

> that iterates over the directory_entry elements of a directory (but does not visit the subdirectories). The iteration order is unspecified, except that each directory entry is visited only once. The special pathnames dot and dot-dot are skipped.

The provided links provide sample codes.

Before C++17, you either have to use [`boost::filesystem`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) (which is actually an anchestor of the `std::filesystem`) or you have to use the OS specific functions which are usually of limited portability.

Concerning the latter, there are already existing questions in SO:

- [How to list files in a directory using the Windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41404711/7478597)
- [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/612097/7478597)
- [How do I get a list of files in a directory in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/306533/7478597)

to list only a few.