# List of all files inside the folder and its subfolders in Windows

Tags: c, windows, directory, msdn

I want to list all the files that run under Task Scheduler by accessing all the files in the **"C:\windows\system32\Tasks"** Directory.

The program should recursively keep opening subfolders in the directory and list all the files. I currently use **Windows OS**.

I tried using the COM library but it doesn't display the tasks in the subfolders. I have 60 tasks but it displays only 12. So, I'm trying to iterate through the Tasks folder instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *de; 
    if ((dir = opendir("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Tasks")) != NULL);
    {
        printf("The startup Programs are:\n");
        while ((de = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
          {
            printf("%s\n", de->d_name);
          }
    closedir(dir);
    }
   getchar();
}
```

I expected the output to display all the files inside the current folder and the subfolders.
However, the output only displays the name of the first folder and exits.

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag: unless OP says otherwise this really looks like C. @OP: C != C++

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, that is for unix. He needs it for Windows. the unix versin won't work.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, both your links are to the same solution.

Comment: @Paul _"He needs it for Windows."_ POSIX functions are mentioned. Should work anyways.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, he mentions posix as he doesn't know what to use under windows. `readdir` is unavailable under MSVC/Windows.

Comment: Raisa, you should use `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile`.

Comment: @Paul OK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883594/microsoft-visual-studio-opendir-and-readdir-how

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404711/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-using-the-windows-api google is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is apparently no full, simple, example of recursively listing directories under windows, here is one:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void listdirs(char *dir, char *mask)
{
    char fspec[1024], fname[1024];
    WIN32_FIND_DATA     dta;
    HANDLE              hDta;

    sprintf(fspec,"%s/%s",dir, mask);

    if ((hDta= FindFirstFile (fspec, &dta)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            if ( !(dta.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) )
            {
                printf ("%s/%s\n", dir, dta.cFileName);
            }
            else
            {
                if (strcmp(dta.cFileName,".")!=0 && strcmp(dta.cFileName,"..")!=0 )
                {
                    sprintf (fname, "%s\\%s", dir, dta.cFileName);
                    listdirs(fname, mask);
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFile (hDta, &dta));

        FindClose(hDta);
    }
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    listdirs(argv[1],argv[2]);  // Usage: progname c:\MyDir *.*
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works well for other folders but doesn't work for the system32\tasks folder.

Comment: If you look at the security attributes of the folder, you will see that only administrators may list the contents of the directory.

Comment: If you add a `printf  ("%s/\n",fname);` after the `sprintf(fname..` you will see it traverses the directories but does not list any files.

Comment: I've run Codeblocks as Administrator, but I'm still unable to read names of files.

Comment: I am also at a loss why it doesn't work for system32/tasks. It has something to do with the security attributes.

Comment: The error message it gives if the Directory doesn't open is "Input/Output error"