# How to use FindNextFile call in Windows to list directory contents?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a small piece of code that is meant to list the contents of a directory using the Windows API.

**CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int wmain() {

    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    std::string dir = "c:\\* "; 
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(dir.c_str(), &data);      // DIRECTORY

    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            std::cout << data.cFileName << std::endl;
        } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &data));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

`Error  C2664    'HANDLE FindFirstFileA(LPCSTR,LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'WIN32_FIND_DATA *' to 'LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA'`

The errors change depending on my attempts at fixes. I have tried the following:

- Tried to change `FindFirstFile` to `FindFirstFileW` / `FindNextFileA`
- Tried to put an `L` in front of directory string `L"C:\\*"`

I have looked at the following related questions:

- [Listing directory contents using C and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314542/listing-directory-contents-using-c-and-windows)
- [How to list files in a directory using the Windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404711/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-using-the-windows-api)

But did not get it to successfully list the contents. Closest I have got is this code which compiles without errors:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(L"C:\\*", &data);

    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            std::cout << data.cFileName << std::endl;
        } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &data));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}
```

This compiles but when I run the binary, it outputs this:

> 0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C
>   0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C
>   0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C
>   0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C 0000009A9DBAF32C

While we are at it, what's the difference between `FindNextFile`, `FindNextFileA` and `FindNextFileW`? I feel like the issue is somehow related to these?

Comment: Use std::wcout instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code snippet, you are clearly compiling your project with `UNICODE` defined (as evident by you being able to pass a `WIN32_FIND_DATA` to `FindNextFileW()` without error).  When `UNICODE` is defined, `WIN32_FIND_DATA` maps to `WIN32_FIND_DATAW`.  But `FindFirstFileA()` wants a `WIN32_FIND_DATAA` instead.  So the *simpliest* solution to that error is to just change  `WIN32_FIND_DATA` to `WIN32_FIND_DATAA` to satisfy the call to `FindFirstFileA()`.  But then you will have a new error because you would be passing a `WIN32_FIND_DATAA` to `FindNextFileW()`, which wants a `WIN32_FIND_DATAW` instead.  So you will need to call `FindNextFileA()` instead to fix that error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

int wmain() {

    WIN32_FIND_DATAA data;
    std::string dir = "c:\\* "; 
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(dir.c_str(), &data);      // DIRECTORY

    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            std::cout << data.cFileName << std::endl;
        } while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &data));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In your second code snippet, `std::cout` does not have an overloaded `operator<<` for `wchar_t` data, but it does have an overload for `void*`.  The `WIN32_FIND_DATAW::cFileName` field is a `wchar_t[]` array, which *decays* into a `wchar_t*` pointer to the 1st character, and all pointers are implicitly convertible to `void*`.  So that is why you are seeing memory addresses being printed.  You need to use `std::wcout` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int wmain()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW data;
    std::wstring dir = L"c:\\*";
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileW(dir.c_str(), &data);

    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            std::wcout << data.cFileName << std::endl;
        } while (FindNextFileW(hFind, &data));
        FindClose(hFind);
    }
}
```

Most Win32 APIs that deal with string data have `A` (ANSI) and `W` (Wide, Unicode) flavors, and provide generic `TCHAR`-based macros to map to one or the other based on the `UNICODE` conditional.  In this case, `FindFirstFile()` maps to either `FindFirstFileA()` or `FindFirstFileW()`, `FindNextFile()` maps to either `FindNextFileA()` or `FindNextFileW()`, `WIN32_FIND_DATA` map to either `WIN32_FIND_DATAA` or `WIN32_FIND_DATAW`, etc.

So the general rule is, the suffix you explicitly state (or omit) in an API function call should also be repeated in any related variable declarations as needed.  If you call an `A` API function explicitly, use appropriate `A` variable types explicitly.  If you call a `W` API function explicitly, use appropriate `W` variable types explicitly.  If you omit `A`/`W` in an API function call, omit it in variable declarations (or replace with `T` for `TCHAR`, if needed).

Comment: Good answer. OP needs to choose between char and wide-char, then settle on the same implementation across both the stdlib and WinAPI, rather than randomly mixing & matching / guessing.

Answer (score 4):

`FindNextFile` is a macro that resolves to either `FindNextFileA` (ANSI) or `FindNextFileW` (Unicode UTF16-LE) depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined (and `_UNICODE`).

So you change `WIN32_FIND_DATA` to `WIN32_FIND_DATAA` as `FindFirstFileA` needs the ANSI version of the parameter.

See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040212-00/?p=40643 for an explanation of the differences between defining `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE`

Comment: To be clear, while this is the solution to make `FindFirstFileA` work, it is not the correct solution in general. It's 2019, write Unicode friendly code. As Hans said in the question comments, the correct solution is to use the `W` versions of the APIs (or the unsuffixed versions, but making sure your build environment defines `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE`, which it should by default on modern versions of Visual Studio), and just send your output to `std::wcout` which supports wide character output.

Comment: _Or_, if the rest of your application is nice and UTF-8, convert to UTF-8 on the way out of this function so you can just use `std::cout` to stream the constituent bytes verbatim to your UTF-8 capable terminal.