# Error in file reading with ifstream

Tags: c++

I'm having issue in the `ifstream` function, I have tried using the `argv[1]` as parameter but wont load the map, the map is located in the same folder of main code.
I'm stucked here and can not debug.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int h;
    int w;
    int var;


    string inputLine;

    ifstream f;
    f.open("map.pgm",ios::in);
    if (!f){
        cout << "error" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Visual Studio can debug. What prevents you from debugging?

Comment: In VS by default program current directory is not where source is, but executable. So either move you `map.pgm` there or specify full path

Comment: Use Process Monitor to find out where it tries to load the map from

Comment: And `ifstream` is not a function

Comment: ***In VS by default program current directory is not where source is, but executable.*** This is wrong. In Visual Studio the default folder is the folder containing the project file unless you changed the default. This way if you run a Debug or Release configuration your data files are in the same place.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path of the file, just to rule out the possibility that your application is looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score -1):

Change this line:

```
if (!f){
```

by this:

```
if (!f.is_open()){
```

BTW you can check current directory path with [GetModuleFileName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875249/how-to-get-current-directory)

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is a solution and why it's preferable to check for just this rather than any error on the stream?

Comment: Don't bother; it isn't.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Well OP stated that he is stuck, and can't debug. So I think checking the file is in right place and opened is a good start. Don't you?

Comment: `if(!f)` is true if the file was not opened.  I don't see that your solution does anything other than narrow the check for all possible errors.