# How do I stream data from retrieved "GetObject()" file to localfile on disk - C++ Aws SDK

Tags: c++, amazon-s3, sdk

I am trying to stream the data in the retrieved s3 file into a local file on disk. However, when I try my current code, I do not get a file stored on my computer, or in any location near the code.

I first request the object from s3 using a getObjectOutcome. After success, I want to create an ofstream and redirect the objects stream buffer to my local object so that I can create a file on disc. However, the following code does not create a file on my computer. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the get object function:

```
bool GetObject(const Aws::String& objectKey,
    const Aws::String& fromBucket,
    const Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration& clientConfig) {
    Aws::S3::S3Client client(clientConfig);

    Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest request;
    request.SetBucket(fromBucket);
    request.SetKey(objectKey);

    Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectOutcome outcome =
        client.GetObject(request);

    if (!outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        const Aws::S3::S3Error& err = outcome.GetError();
        std::cerr << "Error: GetObject: " <<
            err.GetExceptionName() << ": " << err.GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Successfully retrieved '" << objectKey << "' from '"
            << fromBucket << "'." << std::endl;
        std::ofstream localfile;
        localfile.open(objectKey.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        auto retrieved = outcome.GetResult().GetBody().rdbuf();
        localfile << retrieved; 
        std::cout << "Done!";
    }

    return outcome.IsSuccess();
}
```

Here is an image of the memory for local file and retrieved:
[image: image of output]

Would someone teach me what I am doing this wrong, or how to correctly download data from s3 to disc?

Thanks.

I tried downloading some data from s3 to disc. I am having trouble outputting this data via stream buffer to local file. I have been looking online and cannot find a similar problem.

*Update:*

I am now on my second day of trying to figure this out to no avail. For some reason, the code will not even output a file after it has been created to the directory I have set up for the .nc files to be written to.

I have tried the following updates:

```
bool GetObject(const Aws::String& objectKey,
    const Aws::String& fromBucket,
    const Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration& clientConfig) {
    Aws::S3::S3Client client(clientConfig);

    Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest request;
    request.SetBucket(fromBucket);
    request.SetKey(objectKey);

    Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectOutcome outcome =
        client.GetObject(request);

    if (!outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        const Aws::S3::S3Error& err = outcome.GetError();
        std::cerr << "Error: GetObject: " <<
            err.GetExceptionName() << ": " << err.GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Successfully retrieved '" << objectKey << "' from '"
            << fromBucket << "'." << std::endl;

        //create the filename, which will be the objectKey 
        std::string local_file_name = "./netcdf/" + objectKey;
        std::ofstream local_file(local_file_name, std::ios::binary);
        auto &retrieved = outcome.GetResult().GetBody();
        local_file << retrieved.rdbuf();
        std::cout << "Done!";

    }

    return outcome.IsSuccess();
}
```

Then, after opening the ./netcdf folder, there is no output.

Here is the file structure inside my project for reference with the code:

[image: filestructure]

I am still confused as to what I need to do here.

Thank you for all of the help you can offer!

Comment: Did anything end up in the file at all?

Comment: It does not look like it. There is a whole lot of NULL

Comment: Check out the new update with a description on what I am trying now. Thanks for any help you might could provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a folder with `"./"` at the front. This means that the file will be relative to the current working directory (cwd) of the binary. That is likely not the `src` folder

Just to get past your problem, use a full absolute path to see if the rest of your code works.

Also, try adding

```
 // You need "#include <filesystem>" for the next line
 cout << std::filesystem::current_path();
```

To see where the files you made might be

Comment: See here for cwd in C++ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875249/how-to-get-current-directory

Comment: I just found out why it was not working. Accidentally had my debug path to the wrong directory. Rookie mistake.