# unix command result to a variable - char*

Tags: c, char

How can I assign "pwd" (or any other command in that case) result (present working dir) to a variable which is char*?

command can be anything. Not bounded to just "pwd".

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current directory in a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program)

Comment: You could look at using `getcwd()` http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html

Comment: Aah, pwd is just an example. I want to generalize the question....my bad...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with `popen`. That will let you run a command with its standard output directed to a `FILE *` that your parent can read. From there it's just a matter of reading its output like you would any normal file (e.g., with `fgets`, `getchar`, etc.)

Generally, however, you'd prefer to avoid running an external program for that -- you should have [`getcwd`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) available, which will give the same result much more directly.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just call `getcwd()`? It's not part of C's standard library, but it *is* POSIX, and it's very widely supported.

Anyway, if `pwd` was just an example, have a look at `popen()`. That will run an external command and give you a FILE* with which to read its output.

Comment: Thanks but "pwd" is just an example, I am looking for a generalize solution for any command.

Answer (score 2):

There is a POSIX function, [`getcwd()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) for this - I'd use that.

Comment: Thanks but "pwd" is just an example, I am looking for a generalize solution for any command.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *dir;
    dir = getcwd(NULL, 0);
    printf("Current directory is: %s\n", dir);
    free(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm lazy, and like the `NULL, 0` parameters, which is a GNU extension to allocate as large a buffer as necessary to hold the full pathname. (It can probably still fail, if you're buried a few hundred thousand characters deep.)

Because it is allocated for you, you need to `free(3)` it when you're done. I'm done with it quickly, so I `free(3)` it quickly, but that might not be how you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can fork and use one of the execv* functions to call pwd from your C program, but getting the result of that would be messy at best.

The proper way to get the current working directory in a C program is to call char* getcwd(char* name, size_t size);