# Cannot find .txt file to read in c

Tags: c, macos, file

Im new to C and I'm using OS X 10.9.5. I am using Code::Blocks and also tried Xcode but with both of them it seems impossible to open and read a simple .txt file unless I open the Terminal and locate the file myself (using cd ...). The .txt and .c files are in the same folder. How could the program open the text file itself automatically? 
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    FILE *fp;
    char name[50], city [50];
    int age;

    if((fp=fopen("text.txt","r"))) {
        //printf("yes\n");
    } else {
        printf("doesnt open\n");
    }

    while (fscanf(fp,"%s\t%d\t%s\n",name, &age, city)!=EOF) {
        printf("name=%s age=%d city=%s\n",name,age,city);
    }

    fclose (fp);


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is the _program_ (not the .c file) and the text file in the same folder?

Comment: Try opening a new file for write. Then find the directory where the new file has been created. This is the working directory where fopen will look when opening a file for read with a less-than-fully-qualified file name.

Comment: BTW: `fscanf(fp,"%s\t%d\t%s\n",name, &age, city)` works the same as `fscanf(fp,"%s%d%s ",name, &age, city)`.  Suggest using `fscanf(fp,"%49s%d%49s",name, &age, city) == 3`.  (This is not your main issue)

Comment: Youc could do this if the file is in your login ($HOME) directory... `chdir(getenv("HOME"));` or something like `chdir("/users/home/yourname");`

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory is different than you expect. If you run an app through an IDE, the IDE most likely sets a working directory to your app.

To get the current working directory (for checking): [How to get the current directory in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program)