# C utility to print filenames in current directory (Unix)

Tags: c, unix, directory

Fairly new to C and Unix.

I currently have:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{ char * current =  get_current_dir_name();    //where error occurs
  DIR * directory = NULL;
  directory = opendir(current);
  if(directory == NULL)
    return -1;
  struct dirent * ent;

  while((ent = readdir (directory)) != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", ent -> d_name);

  if(closedir(directory) < 0)
    return -1;
}
```

I'm being told: dir.c:15: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Clearly doing something pretty silly and could use some help.

Comment: Where is `get_current_dir_name()` declared? Your warning tells you the problem - C thinks `get_current_dir_name()` is returning an `int` (the default type when no one has told it otherwise)

Comment: Why is `stdio` inside `" "`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard function to get the name of the current working directory is [`getcwd()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd), not `get_current_dir_name()`.  `get_current_dir_name()` is a GNU extension and is only available if the macro `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined prior to including `<unistd.h>`, and its use is not recommended.

In your case, `_GNU_SOURCE` is not defined, so consequently `get_current_dir_name()` is not the name of a declared function.  So when the C compiler sees your try to call it, it generates an *implicit declaration*.

Implicit function declarations create a declaration at the point of use declaring the function to take an arbitrary number and types of arguments and returning `int`.  Hence, in this case, the compiler thinks it has an `int` being assigned to a variable of type `char*`, so it generates the "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast warning".

Implicit declarations are a deprecated feature of the C language and are in fact removed from the C99 edition of the language, although modern compilers still often accept them (with warnings) even in C99 mode.  Even in C89 mode, I highly recommend compiling with your warning level as high as possible to catch errors like this, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` if you can handle it.