# How to build libzmq on OSX?

Tags: macos, cmake, zeromq

I am trying to build libzmq on OSX.
I have git cloned the repository found at this link: https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq.

I am following these instructions:

[image]

When I run:

```
sudo make -j4 install
```

I get the following error:

[image: li]

I can't seem to find more information about `get_current_dir_name()`.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, replace the *image* of build log with the build log itself (as **text**). Using images just for textual information is discouraged on Stack Overflow. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here:

```
test_bind_fuzzer.cpp:44:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'get_current_dir_name'
```

is likely due to a lack of support of your compiler. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26668503/3987854) explains that `get_current_dir_name()` is a "*GNU extension, and is only available if the macro `_GNU_SOURCE` is defined prior to including `<unistd.h>`*". Apparently, yours is not set up this way.

This error was the result of building one of the ZeroMQ tests. So, while not a solution, one workaround is to remove the tests from your build. Try running this `cmake` command instead:

```
cmake -DZMQ_BUILD_TESTS=OFF ..
```