# C - Obtaining directory path

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I'm writing a program that when executed in a directory will generate a text file with all of the contents in that directory. I'm getting the directory path from the `**argv` to main and because I'm using netbeans and cygwin I have to do some string manipulation of the obtained path in my `char* get_path(char **argv)` function. The directory path size will always vary therefore I'm assigning space with malloc to store it in the memory.

Program snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "dbuffer.h"  //my own library
#include "darray.h"   //my own library

ARR* get_dir_contents( char* path)
    {
    DBUFF *buff = NULL;
    ARR *car = NULL;   
    DIR *dir_stream = NULL;
    struct dirent *entry = NULL;

    dir_stream = opendir(path);
    if(opendir(path)==NULL) printf("NULL");

    //... more code here 
    return car;
    }

char* get_path(char **argv)
    {
    char *path = malloc(sizeof(char)* sizeof_pArray( &argv[0][11] ) + 3 );

    strcpy(path, "C:");
    strcat(path, &argv[0][11]);

    printf("%s, sizeof: %d \n",path, sizeof_pArray(path));
    return path;
    }

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
    {  

    char *p = get_path(argv);

    ARR *car = get_dir_contents(&p[0]);

    //... more code here 

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

The problem is that the string that I have doesn't initialize the `dir_stream` pointer. I suspect it is because of some discrepancy between pointers and string literals but I can't pinpoint what it is exactly. Also the fact that dirent library function expects `DIR *opendir(const char *dirname);` **const char** might have something to do with it.

Output:

```
C:/Users/uk676643/Documents/NetBeansProjects/__OpenDirectoryAndListFiles/dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/__opendirectoryandlistfiles, sizeof: 131 
NULL
RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,819, total time: 2s)
```

Comment: `sizeof_pArray` sounds wrong, why not use the standard function strlen ? also there is no need to pass `**` to get_path just declare it as a normal `char*` and pass `*argv` instead to make it simpler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program

Comment: @CyberSpock it's my own function that gets string length + terminating character

Comment: why do you have the 11 offset ?

Comment: @stark I don't see why you commented that link, I don't have problem getting the directory but rather passing the string

Comment: @CyberSpock I have the offset because without it I get the following: `/cygdrive/c/Users/uk676643/Documents/NetBeansProjects/__OpenDirectoryAndListFiles/dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/__opendirectoryandlistfiles` directory

Comment: ok gotcha , not easy to know without having cygwin

Comment: Just pointing out what might be a better way.

Comment: In case `opendir()` fails instead of `printf("NULL")` do a `perror("opendir() failed")` and probably get enlightened what is going wrong.

Comment: If your program is built for cygwin, you shouldn't try to "nativize" paths. Just use them as they are. `opendir` will work on `"/cygwin/c/Users/blah"`.

Comment: @alk I didn't know about the `perror()` function, I've tried it and indeed got enlightened by it. Turns out that the path that I was getting included the file name itself. What I had to do was to get rid of the last bit after `...Cygwin_4.x-Windows/` and now the program works as I wanted it to work. Thank you!

Comment: @wumpusQ.Wumbley You're right the program works without nativazing the paths which made my life easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

there are some things here that can go wrong so 
I would suggest doing something like this instead

```
char* get_path(char *argv)
{
  char *path = malloc(sizeof(char)* strlen(argv) ); 

  if (path != NULL)
  {
    strcpy(path, "C:");
    strcat(path, argv + 11);

    printf("%s, sizeof: %d \n",path, strlen(path));
  }
  return path;
}


...
char* p = get_path(*argv);
```

note: you don't need the extra 3 bytes, since you allocate including the 11 bytes you later skip. although instead of having the 11 bytes offset you may want to decompose the string and then later put it together so that it is portable. E.g. using `strtok` you could split that path and replace the parts you don't need.

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion and my problem still persists

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer the above code should take care of any pointer error but maybe you are formatting the path wrong. check the errno after calling opendir to determine the error.

Comment: Turns out that my pointers were correct but the path that I was getting included the file name itself and I had to get rid of the last bit of the path. I've done it using the method you suggested of using `strtok()` . Now the program is running as I wanted it to. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a simple confusion about argv ? Please insert the following lines
just at the beginning of your main() , is it what you expected ?

```
printf("\n argv[0]== %s" , argv[0]  );
getchar();

printf("\n argv[1]== %s" , argv[1]  );
getchar();
```

OK, so we work from argv[0] , please try this for get_path

```
char *get_path(char *argv)
{
int i=0;
// +2 to add the drive letter
char *path = malloc(sizeof(char)* strlen(argv)+2 );

if (path != NULL)
{
 strcpy(path, "C:");
 strcat(path, argv);

 // we get the path and the name of calling program
 printf("\n  path and program== %s",path);
 printf("%s, sizeof: %d \n",path, strlen(path));
 // now remove calling program name
   for( i=strlen(path) ; ; i--)
   {
     // we are working in windows
      if(path[i]=='\\') break;
      path[i]='\0';
   }

 }
 return path;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm sure there's no confusion plus I verified checked : 

`argv[0]== /cygdrive/c/Users/uk676643/Documents/NetBeansProjects/__OpenDirectoryAndListFiles/dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/__opendirectoryandlistfiles

 argv[1]== (null)`

Comment: As it turned out argv[0] supplied me with the path AND the file name which  I didn't know about but was able to get rid of the file name. +1 For `// we get the path and the name of calling program` .