# Directory Navigation with C++

Tags: c++, linux

I'm learning how to develop C++ programs without an IDE by using gcc and gdb for my debugger. Up to now, I've developed Python in the terminal with emacs but shied away from C++ because I was intimidated by makefiles, etc. Now that I'm working in Linux with my C++ program, I was wondering something about the way C++ works with directories.

I have a directory structure as follows

```
               Parent
           /           \
Data Folder             Program Dir
    |                      |
407 subdirectories      <program files>
```

Developing python scripts on a linux machine makes it easy to change directories by just storing os.getcwd(), using os.chdir() to change directories to a target, and then using it again to return to the previous directory. My question is, can I do the same thing with C++ where I navigate to the parallel directory Data Folder containing 407 subdirectories in a similar way to Python?

I've seen the following post so I know about getcwd in C++:
[How to get the current directory in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program)

However, I'm asking because I remember having to do something in Xcode where I tell it where to look for my data since I wasn't able to get it to navigate directories intuitively (like Python.) I assume I don't need to do that again.

**What's the best way to do this (switch dirs, perform tasks, switch back) without using boost filesystem?**

Comment: Use chdir? (Note that chdir is part of your operating system, not part of C++)

Comment: In c++, it's more common that there's a source directory, a data directory, and a build directory. When your project gets built by a makefile or whatnot, your binary ends up in the build directory, and any data files it needs get copied there. You are supposed to run the binary in that folder and it may grab the data files using relative paths. You could also have some kind of "asset_path_marker" file or something to tell it where to look for data. You don't need to manually change directories, just open `fstream`'s with a relative path as the string, and you can error out if it doesn't open.

Comment: Both python and C++ ultimately rely on system libraries to do things like change the current working directory of a program. So I would look at the linux manpages for the C API to `chdir()`, etc.

Comment: Why, in either python or c++, change the directory?  If you desire access to a file in directory `X`, you should open it by eg `open(os.path.join(`X`, <some-file>))`.  (temporarily changing the directory is still changing global state ... that may cause unintended side effects in multithreaded programs)

Comment: @donkopotamus  How would I do that in C++?

Comment: Note that in C++17, boost's awesome filesystem library will likely become standard.

Comment: If you on a POSIX(ish) system (e.g. Linux, BSD, OSX, etc...), you can get documentation for system calls using `man` pages.  Try using `man chdir` or `man opendir`.  All operating system calls should generally have a `man` page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directory functions in dirent.h to obtain the directory contents. Use the opendir function to open the directory, then traverse the directory using readdir and finally call closedir to close the directory handle.

This is a system call in linux/unix, won't work in Windows or other OS.