# shell code for executing shell instructions

Tags: c, shell

I want to execute cd command like the shell itself in my code ...
my code will ask from the user the whole command like "cd /desktop" and i try to use chdir(path) but there is a mistake here in part of executing cd in my code .. please help

```
void main(void) {
    char in[512];
    pid_t id;
    int status,x,y,i = 1;
    char *f[512];
    char *v;
    char *s;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("shell>");

        fgets(in,512, stdin);
        int size = strlen(in);// calculate dim of in execpt null
        in[size-1] = '\0'; //null at the end because ls\n not executable
        v = strtok(in, " ");
        f[0] = v;
        while (v = strtok(NULL, " ")){
            f[i] = v;
            i++;
        }
        f[i] = NULL;

         y=strcmp(f[0],"exit");      
         if(y==0)
             break;

         x=strcmp(f[0],"cd");
         if(x==0){
             s=f[2]; // this should be the path is it right?
             chdir(s);
         }

         id=fork();

         if (id==0){ //child
             execvp(f[0],f);
             perror("failure");
             exit(1);
         }
         else //parent
         {
             waitpid(id,&status,0);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `s = f[2]` it should be `s = f[1]`. But anyway you might want to use just `in` and write `s = &in[2]`, that you can also say `cd This is my fancy dirname`

Comment: How do you verify the results of your program?  I'm tempted to believe that you might not be aware of the definition of *current directory* in a POSIX environment - it's a property of the running process. Your program and the shell you run it from each have their own *cwd*.  A child process cannot change properties of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should at least move

```
i = 1;
```

into the while loop, i.e.

```
while(1)
{
    i = 1;
```

Further

```
s=f[2]; // this should be the path is it right?
```

I would expect it to be `f[1]`

**Example based on your code**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char in[512];
    int status,x,y,i = 1;
    char *f[512];
    char *v;
    char *s;
    char cwd[1024];  // ADDED THIS

    while(1)
    {
        i = 1;  // ADDED THIS

        getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));        // ADDED THIS - print current dir
        fprintf(stdout, "%s - ", cwd);

        printf("shell>");

        fgets(in,512, stdin);

        printf(" %s", in);   // ADDED THIS

        int size = strlen(in);// calculate dim of in execpt null
        in[size-1] = '\0'; //null at the end because ls\n not executable
        v = strtok(in, " ");
        f[0] = v;
        while (v = strtok(NULL, " ")){
            f[i] = v;
            i++;
        }
        f[i] = NULL;

         y=strcmp(f[0],"exit");      
         if(y==0)
             break;

         x=strcmp(f[0],"cd");
         if(x==0){
             s=f[1];         // CHANGED THIS
             printf("path=%s\n", s);  // just a print for debug
             //chdir(s);              // just removed for debug
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

> cd dir1
>
> cd dir2
>
> exit

Output:

> shell> cd dir1
>
> path=dir1
>
> shell> cd dir2
>
> path=dir2
>
> shell> exit

Comment: @A.Mohsen - could you be more specific - what is not working

Comment: when i do ur modification it did not implement cd !! i.e chang the current directory

Comment: First comment out the `chdir` and put `printf("path=%s\n", s);` to check that the string is correct.

Comment: the string is correct but when i run the code i found no such file or directory.... i made a file named "testdir" in desktop when i type "cd testdir"
the output print  the path correctly but no change in the current directory.

Comment: @A.Mohsen - Hmmm.. `i made a file named "testdir" ` ! A file? You can't `cd` into a file. Do you mean a directory? Anyway - you are probably running the program in another directory than you think

Comment: i mean directory but what u mean running in another directory?
please can u copy my code in my post and test it in ur own pc and tell me the main modification i should do ..

Comment: @A.Mohsen - the directory where you start your program. You say you created a directory on the desktop but are you also sure you run the program from the desktop? Maybe you should start by printing current directory. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program

Comment: yes my c file in desktop and i run if from desktop in shell and the directory which i made is in the desktop

Comment: @A.Mohsen - so in the shell you can do `cd testdir` ? Have you added the code I linked? Add it both before and after the `chdir`

Comment: @A.Mohsen - I can't test it myself now but maybe I'll check it in an hour or so

Comment: @A.Mohsen - the program works fine for me. Do you still have problems?