# get_cwd() from linked directory

Tags: c, unistd.h

I have a program to print the current directory which I got from

[How to get the current directory in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program#298518)

which works very well.

However, how can I do this for a ***linked*** directory?

For example, I need

```
/home/user/Directory
```

instead of the linked directory

```
/mnt/data/user/Directory
```

that is,

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user  user 23 Apr  2  2015 Directory -> /mnt/data/user/Directory//
```

in contrast to

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 user  user 23 Apr  2  2015 Directory
```

I am trying to expand my C skills, maybe there is something I'm missing?

Comment: use an absolute directory?

Comment: Do you want to get the path a symlink points to? You can do that with readlink(2).

Comment: @AndySchweig: It is clear that the op is not wanting to get the path a symlink points to.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand the situation now. Correct me if I'm wrong. You've gotten to this directory by cd'ing to `/home/user/Directory`. Once there, you run your program and `getcwd`returns `/mnt/data/user/Directory`, but what you want is `/home/user/Directory`. Is that it? If so, the system doesn't know that you got to that directory by following a symlink, so it can't give you `/home/user/Directory`. However, most shells set the `PWD` environment variable to the current directory as determined by what you've been cd'ing to, so `PWD` will most likely contain `/home/user/Directory`after cd'ing to that directory. I'm not sure if that helps in your situation.

Comment: This is basically correct.  Lookup [`cd`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) in POSIX.  The `-P` and `-L` options specify physical and logical directory name.  The `-P` option works like `realpath()` or `getcwd()`, working out the direct path from root to the given/current directory.  The `-L` option requires shell support; the shell must remember how it got to the current directory, and it uses the saved information to get back to where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo but not with much error checking :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h> /* For retrieving file stats */
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main()
{

struct stat info;
char *target;
char *const ptr=getenv("PWD");

printf("Current working directory : %s\n",ptr);

/* Now, checking to see if your current directory is a link */

if(lstat(ptr,&info)==0)
{
  if(S_ISLNK(info.st_mode))
  {
    target=(char*)malloc((info.st_size+1)*sizeof(char));
    readlink(ptr,target,info.st_size+1);
    target[info.st_size]='\0';
    printf("Current directory is a link\n");
    printf("Target directory : %s\n",target);
    free(target);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Current directory is not a link\n");
  }
}
else
{
   printf("Sorry! Cannot stat the file\n");
   exit(-1);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is subvertible: `PWD=/epsilon/delta/gamma/beta/alpha env | grep PWD` shows that `PWD` can be set to an arbitrary value.

Comment: It also isn't wholly reliable even when not directly subverted.  It detects whether the last element of the path is a symlink, but intermediate elements could be a symlink.  Given a real directory `/home/person/subdir1`, containing another real directory `/home/person/subdir1/leafdir` and a symbolic link `/home/person/subdir2` which references `subdir1`, and the user does `cd /home/person/subdir2/leafdir`, then your code will report 'not a link' even though a symlink was traversed to get to `leafdir`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Thankyou for pointing out that `PWD` is subvertible.. But to check if a symbolic directory was traversed to get to the current directory is not a part of op's mission I guess..

Comment: The second one is a corner case, not a major issue.  You can get some mildly interesting results out of it.  The symlink needs to skip over more directories to be really interesting, but then explaining the setup is more complex, and the required results aren't completely clear anyway.  On a Mac, doing `(cd subdir2/leafdir; /bin/pwd)` prints the path via `subdir2`; doing `(cd subdir2/leafdir; unset PWD; /bin/pwd)` prints the path via `subdir1` — as would using the `realpath()` system call.