# When creating a file in C++, where is the created file saved at?

Tags: c++

After executing the code, i couldn't find the newly created file in my desktop. Could anyone tell where a created file will be saved in?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
     ofstream testfile("testing.txt");
     if (testfile.is_open())
     {
        testfile << "This is a line.\n";
        testfile << "This the second line.\n";
        testfile.close();
     }
     else cout << "Unable to open file";
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***where is the created file saved at?*** Possibly depends on your ide. If you are not using an IDE it probably is the same folder as the executable.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think he means the file created by ofstream.

Comment: You are indeed correct. I have misread.

Comment: In the current working directory. You can print it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/298510/72178.

Answer (score 1):

"testing.txt" is a "relative" path (as opposed to a fully qualified path such as "C:\testing.txt"). Relative paths are always relative to the current working directory, which is usually where your executable is launched from. Though certain IDE's like Visual Studio sometimes set the CWD to a different folder in your project directory by default.

Edit: The reason Visual Studio can be different is that it technically launches the executable from a different directory. What really matters is where the executable is launched from.... which is usually where it is located, but not always.