# Why is the relative path of my file not being recognized by my application?

Tags: c, path, opencl, filepath

I am trying to run OpenCL code on Eclipse (I am working on RHEL 6.6). One of the steps for this involves specifying the path of the OpenCL file (with a `.cl` extension) to open and read it.

Note: *I am using the code from [this](https://github.com/claf/MJPEG/tree/master/tima_seq_version) github link.*

The code I have written for carrying out the above-mentioned task is as follows:

```
FILE *fp;
const char fileName[]= "/root/Downloads/tima_seq_version/src/invCosine.cl";
size_t source_size;
char *source_str;

/* Load kernel source file */
fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
if (!fp) {
fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
exit(1);
}
```

The code above contains the absolute path for the file and works properly. However, when I run the same code by using the relative path for the file like this:

```
FILE *fp;
const char fileName[]= "./invCosine.cl";
size_t source_size;
char *source_str;

/* Load kernel source file */
fp = fopen(fileName, "rb");
if (!fp) {
fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
exit(1);
}
```

I get the response `Failed to load kernel` on the console. I even tried to specify the path as just `invCosine.cl` instead of `./invCosine.cl` and I keep getting the same negative reponse.

My file directories for this program look like this:

[image]

**Why is the relative path of the file not being recognized?**

Update:

I moved `invCosine.cl` out of the `src` directory and put it in the main directory `tima_seq_version`. After that, both path names (`./invCosine.cl` and `invCosine.cl`) were letting the code run properly to completion.

What is the reason for this? My `main.c` is in the directory `src`. **It made sense to put my `.cl` in the SAME directory and call it WITHOUT using its absolute path**. Nevertheless, the relative path did not get recognized. But after I moved the .cl file to the parent directory, the relative path was accepted and the application began running properly.

**Why is the file being recognized in the parent directory but not in the current directory?**

Comment: Do you have permissions for /root/Downloads/?

Comment: @WLGfx I have permission for /root/Downloads/.

Comment: / = root directory ./ = current directory ../ = parent directory You can usually skip the ./

Comment: @WLGfx I understand how to specify directories. Thanks to xenoid, I now understand that one has to know the cwd when specifying paths. How can I know what my cwd (if I want to specify the relative path of a file) is WITHOUT writing a function in my code?

Comment: You don't **have to** know your PWD when you use relative paths. If the relative path comes from the user, you can assume that the user has set the PWD  for your process. S/he knows, and if you do it properly you don't care about the actual value. This is how most Unix commands work. But if your process wnat to load process-related files (config file, etc...) then using relative paths (ie, path relative to the PWD) is fraught with peril. You can use paths relative to the executable file, but this is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @xenoid  _If the relative path comes from the user, you can assume that the user has set the PWD for your process. S/he knows, and if you do it properly you don't care about the actual value_. Which _user_ are you referring to? I also don't understand what you mean by _process_ in the context of my application. I am specifying the path of the file in `main.c` so I would assume that my pwd is the directory which contains `main.c`.

Comment: @xenoid  I can open the terminal in any directory and get _the path of the directory I am currently in_ by typing `pwd`. So the output for `pwd` changes depending upon the directory I am in.

Comment: `pwd` reports your "current directory"/"working directory", which in other words is "the directory you are in" (at list on Unix systems..)

Comment: @xenoid I understand that. I don't understand these statements of yours:  _If the relative path comes from the user, you can assume that the user has set the PWD for your process. S/he knows, and if you do it properly you don't care about the actual value_. I am not sure which _user_ you are referring to and what you mean by _process_.

Comment: Process is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). The "working directory" is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). The "user" is whatever need to run your code (human, cron job....).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What counts for relative paths is the current directory of the process (as returned by `getcwd()`), not the directory of the executable. If you want to know where the executable is, in Linux you can use readlink("/proc/self/exe",...). Other Unixen have similar ways (`/proc/{pid}/file`...).

Comment: Should I use the `getcwd()` command in my code (as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program) link) every time to know my current working directory?

Comment: No, but it would be very useful a a debugging tool. Each time you can't load a file with a relative path, wonder what the actual current directory is...