# even if the file exiists it shows no file or directory

Tags: c, linux

```
char check[] = "05634";
char pass[4];
// printf("enter the user name\n");
// scanf(" %s",check);
printf("enter the password\n");
scanf(" %s", pass);
char ch;
char ultra[100];

// char filespec[strlen(check)+1];
// snprintf(filespec,sizeof(filespec),"%s",check);

int fd;
if ((fd = open(check, O_RDONLY)) != -1) {
  // ch=fgetc(fp1);
  int i = 0;
  int flag = 0;
  read(fd, ultra, 100);
  // ultra[i]='\0';
  char *token = strtok(ultra, "\n");
  while (token != NULL) {
    printf("the token is %s\n", token);
    if (strcmp(pass, token) == 0) {
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
  }
  if (flag == 1) {
    printf("success\n");
  } else {
    printf("hry");
  }

  close(fd);
} else {
  perror(" cl");
}
```

when i run this even if the file exits in the same directory it shows no file or directory ?why is this so ?cant we pass a variable in the open argument i need to take the check as a input and then check does the file exists or not how can i do tht ?

Comment: Use perror to identify what is going wrong

Comment: in perror its showing no file or directory while the file is there

Comment: Can you paste ls -l output from where you are executing this

Comment: My guess: You are not running the program in the correct directory

Comment: To debug: Add code to print the current working directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program

Comment: when i am directly passing "05634" in open its opening the file but passing it within the variable doesnt make it

Comment: @Exautica2k16 Are you saying that `fd = open("05634", O_RDONLY))` works but `fd = open(check, O_RDONLY))` fails ?

Comment: What value are you entering for the tiny `char pass[4];` which may be adjacent to `char check[] = "05634";` in memory? You are using `scanf(" %s", pass);` which is ripe to cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: @4386427 yes it is

Comment: Try: `scanf(" %s", pass);` --> `scanf(" %3s", pass);`