# How do I preserve the xcode working directory when compiling into an exec?

Tags: c, xcode, compilation

I coded a relatively simple C program in XCode that I can input unformatted text files with vocabulary lists into and it returns me an html file that has them in a nice table. It works completely fine when run in Xcode, it pulls the files from the Working Directory I set and puts the html files back in there. 
Still, I don't want to have to open XCode every time I want to run this program. I tried compiling it through the command line but the finished exec doesn't find the files it should be opening, whether they're in the Working Directory set in Xcode or the same one as the exec. I've tried entering the whole file path but that doesn't help it find them either. Here's the code for the project:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char name1[50], name2[50], Eng[15][256], Kanji[15][256], Roma[15][256]; //declare file names and string arrays
    FILE *fptr; //declare file pointer

    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%s",name2); //input input file, has to be .txt

    printf("\nOutput: ");
    scanf("%s",name1); //input output file, has to be .html

    int i, m;
    printf("\nNumber: ");
    scanf("%d",&m); //input number of kanji in list

    if ((fptr = fopen(name2,"r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // error in case input file doesn't exist
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i=0;i<m;i++) {
        fscanf(fptr,"%s%s%s", Eng[i], Kanji[i], Roma[i]); //reads the list into the arrays
    }

    fptr = fopen(name1,"w");

    fprintf(fptr,"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<head>\n<meta charset='utf-8'>\n<script src='/Volumes/PRIVAT/Hobbies/Code/ressources/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>\n\n<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kosugi+Maru' rel='stylesheet'>\n\n<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>\n<script src='script.js'></script>\n\n</head>\n<body>\n<table>\n<colgroup> <col id='col1' span='1'> </colgroup>\n<colgroup> <col id='col2' span='2'> </colgroup>\n\n<caption>WEEK 1</caption>\n<tr>\n<th>English</th>\n<th>Kanji</th>\n<th>Reading</th>\n</tr>"); //writes constant part of html file

    for (i=0;i<m;i++) {
        fprintf(fptr,"\n<tr>\n<td>%s</td>\n<td>%s</td>\n<td>%s</td>\n</tr>",Eng[i],Kanji[i],Roma[i]); // writes variable part of html file
    }

    fprintf(fptr,"\n</body>"); //closing html

    fclose(fptr); //closes output 


    return 0;
}
```

The html is fine, so don't bother trying to read that here. Really my only question is whether there's a way to compile this project to run in terminal that preserves the working directory. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What error do you get when running the executable from the command line?

Comment: The one in the code, "Error! opening file", for when the pointer is NULL. It means the input file can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. The working directory of your executable is where you run it from, not where the executable is located.

You can add a call to `getcwd` to see what the current working directory for your program is set to ([from this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298518)). It is also helpful to add a call to `perror` if `fopen` returns `NULL` so that you can see the reason why it failed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    char name1[50], name2[50], Eng[15][256], Kanji[15][256], Roma[15][256]; //declare file names and string arrays
    FILE *fptr; //declare file pointer

    // print current working directory
    char cwd[PATH_MAX];
    if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
        printf("Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
    } else {
        perror("getcwd() error");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Input: ");
    scanf("%s",name2); //input input file, has to be .txt

    printf("\nOutput: ");
    scanf("%s",name1); //input output file, has to be .html

    int i, m;
    printf("\nNumber: ");
    scanf("%d",&m); //input number of kanji in list

    if ((fptr = fopen(name2,"r")) == NULL){
        perror("Error! opening file");
        // error in case input file doesn't exist
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i=0;i<m;i++) {
        fscanf(fptr,"%s%s%s", Eng[i], Kanji[i], Roma[i]); //reads the list into the arrays
    }

    fptr = fopen(name1,"w");

    fprintf(fptr,"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<head>\n<meta charset='utf-8'>\n<script src='/Volumes/PRIVAT/Hobbies/Code/ressources/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>\n\n<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kosugi+Maru' rel='stylesheet'>\n\n<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>\n<script src='script.js'></script>\n\n</head>\n<body>\n<table>\n<colgroup> <col id='col1' span='1'> </colgroup>\n<colgroup> <col id='col2' span='2'> </colgroup>\n\n<caption>WEEK 1</caption>\n<tr>\n<th>English</th>\n<th>Kanji</th>\n<th>Reading</th>\n</tr>"); //writes constant part of html file

    for (i=0;i<m;i++) {
        fprintf(fptr,"\n<tr>\n<td>%s</td>\n<td>%s</td>\n<td>%s</td>\n</tr>",Eng[i],Kanji[i],Roma[i]); // writes variable part of html file
    }

    fprintf(fptr,"\n</body>"); //closing html

    fclose(fptr); //closes output 

    return 0;
}
```