# unable to read memory with inheritance

Tags: c++

I cant save & load my data in inheritance class.

when codes are get in to load Function debuger said unable to read memory and cant access to member funtion

Object is super class, CPlayer is subclass

```
CMainGame::CMainGame()
    :player(nullptr),field(nullptr), save_load(nullptr)
{
    field = new CField();
    save_load = new CSave_Load;

}
void CMainGame::select_class()
{
    case 4:
      //player = new CPlayer;
      player = new CPlayer("", 0.f, 0.f, 0, 0, 0);
      save_load->Load(player);
      return;
}
```

save_load header & cpp

```
class CSave_Load
{
public:
    CSave_Load();
    ~CSave_Load();

    void Save(class CObject* _player);
    void Load(class CObject* _player);
};
//Load Function

void CSave_Load::Load(CObject* _player)
{
FILE* fp = nullptr;
   errno_t err = fopen_s(&fp, "./Data/Save.txt", "rb");
   if (err == 0)
   {
    fread(_player, sizeof(CObject), 1, fp);
    cout << "불러오기 성공" << endl;
    fclose(fp);
   }
    else
      cout << "불러오기 실패" << endl;
      system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain what is `CObject`? If you have something else than very basic type, you should write serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Cobject is super class for CPlayer which has struct in basic type, and constructor, destructor and some member function

Comment: if you read `sizeof(CObject)`, you will not get a `CObject`, not a `CPlayer`. You need to implement proper serialization/deserialization mechanism, or use a library that do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using VisualStudio?

It is possible that the directory from which the EXE is being run, is not the source code directory, as VisualStudio builds out of source.

What happens when you full path? The code seems "OK"ish, but it's really hard to guess without seeing the full picture.

Comment: yes i'm using Visual Studio 2015. i think that code is OK too. and it sometimes run normaly... can i send my full project??

Comment: No you don't :)

But... look into the settings - and verify that the project is running from the source directory and not build directory.

Comment: how can i check them?

Comment: Just a side note - you marked the answer as accepted. However, you still did not fix the problem.. so...

Regarding the "how do I check"... look in the project settings. Eventually you will find it (not using VisualStudio - can't help you there). However - here is a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program

Comment: i found project files but i cant solve my problem lol but it was helpful. i should ask this problem to my professor

Answer (score 0):

finally i solve this problem by sending struct for argument in save, load function
Compiler didn't know CObject or CPlayer size because they are too heavy

```
INFO* CSave_Load::Load(INFO* _info)
{
FILE* fp = nullptr;
   errno_t err = fopen_s(&fp, "./Data/Save.txt", "rb");
   if (err == 0)
   {
    fread(_info, sizeof(INFO), 1, fp);
    cout << "불러오기 성공" << endl;
    fclose(fp);
   }
    else
      cout << "불러오기 실패" << endl;
      system("pause");
    return _info;
}
```

INFO is struct in CObject class