# Why the ifstream does not read anything

Tags: c++

I was using the `ifstream` , but the program does not read anything from the input file . The program runs in macOS 10.14 , my complier is clang 10.0.1, I put the source code and the input file in the same folder.

```
std::string contents;
std::vector<std::string> ContainerOfString;
int main(){
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("test.txt");// test.txt is in the same folder with the source code
    if(ifs){
        while(ifs>>contents){
            ContainerOfString.push_back(contents);
        }
        for(auto &i:ContainerOfString){
            std::cout<<i<<" ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You check if the stream opened, which is good, but you don't do anything to distinguish between failing to open and opening an empty file. "test.txt" is probably not found.

Comment: It doesn't print anything or doesn't open at all? Have you checked whether you get inside the condition or not?

Comment: Try putting the text file in the same location as the binary

Comment: The input file needs to be in the current "working directory" of your program; all relative paths are resolved relative to that directory. What it is depends on how you're running the program.

Comment: test.txt actually exists, I put it exactly the same folder with my source code.

Comment: @OkitaSan498 Yes, that's mentioned in the question. But it doesn't mean that's the right place to put it. The working directory and the source file directory aren't necessarily the same. Please read the previous comments carefully, answer the questions and try the suggestions provided in them.

Comment: @OkitaSan498 If the file name is not absolute the code looks for it based on the current working directory. The current working directory is not always the same as where the source is, the current directory is usually the working direcory of the parent application that started your code. See: [How to get the current directory in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program)

Comment: @OkitaSan498 PS. How do you know it successfully opened the file. There is no error message that tells you if it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::string contents;
std::vector<std::string> ContainerOfString;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("test.txt"); // test.txt is in the same folder with the source code

    if (ifs)
    {
        while (ifs >> contents)
        {
            ContainerOfString.push_back(contents);
        }
        for (auto &i : ContainerOfString)
        {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "file not found" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Have a mechanism to check if the text file is found by your code. It is likely that you spelt your text file wrong, or it is not in the same directory as your main code or something else is preventing your file from being read. Also check to see that the text file is not empty because that will not produce any output from your code as well.