# how to get file path from stat

Tags: c, linux

I would like to write a program in C for linux that runs with a file name as an argument, which prints a path to it. I wonder if this can be read from the stat function?

Example:

> ./a.out abc

> Path:     /users/staff/rty/kania/SK/4.staty/abc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current directory in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program)

Comment: You might need to look up the POSIX `realpath()` function.

Answer (score 3):

> Can [the full filepath] be read from the stat function?

No. [stat()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) returns `struct stat`, which does *NOT* have an entry for "directory".  Because, among other good reasons, a [linked file](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/linking-linux-filesystem) might exist in *multiple* directories at the same time.

You *can* use stat() to verify that the filepath you gave in the command line (either `abc.txt` or `/my/folder/abc.txt`) exists.

You can use [getcwd()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) to get your program's current directory.

You might also consider [path_resolution()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html), if it happens to be applicable to your OS and your "use case".