# Gtk3 - how to find image in current directory? (gtk_image_new_from_file) (i'm using C)

Tags: c, image, gtk3

I'm quite new to Gtk3 and just learned how to load an image, but I do not want it to be hardcoded in, so I can share my app and it works for everyone without changing anything.

```
image = gtk_image_new_from_file("/users/me/desktop/game/earth.png");
```

I've tried using "./earth.png" because I know that works in legit everything else, but it didn't.
As I mentioned before, I'm quite new to Gtk3 so sorry if I'm making you cringe. (btw I checked the docs and YouTube before asking this)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current directory in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program)

Comment: image = gtk_image_new_from_file("earth.png");

Comment: @Michi i already tried that

Comment: @BigmancozmoPlayz Could you please provide a small program so that I can compile and check it?

Comment: Don't worry i figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my solution with @Gerhardh's post of detecting current directory and [this](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/c-program-to-concatenate-two-strings/) TutorialGateway page on concatenating without strcat (i couldn't get strcat working). I also put a small README.md in the game folder on where to place the images, because they must be in a certain directory (home directory)

Comment: Getting the current directory is straightforward with GTK because we have glib. Just try [g_get_current_dir](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-get-current-dir) Function.

Comment: Try this: `const char *const icon_name = "image.png"; char *cur_dir = g_strdup_printf ( "%s/%s", g_get_current_dir(), icon_name ); g_print ( "The path to the file: %s\n", cur_dir ); g_free( cur_dir );`