# Xcode can't find files that exist (using c++ fopen)

Tags: c++, xcode, cocoa

I've been running into this strange problem lately where in my Cocoa app project in Xcode I get the error that the file was not found when using "fopen" (errno 2), called from a C++ file. I made sure to copy these files into the project's directory, then I dragged them from the Finder directory into the Xcode project tree. And finally, in the scheme's options I checked "use custom directory" and entered the directory where I have the project and all the files. The programme builds fine, but during runtime I get a BAD ACCESS error and I can see that my FILE* variable is still NULL. The command that throws the exception is actually "fread" two lines later, but it's only because "fopen" didn't do its job.

This whole setup has worked fine before in pure C++ projects. But this is different because it started as a Cocoa app in Objective-C (because I intended to use C++ for the programme's main logic). At some point I also had to change the extensions of all the ".m" files to ".mm" or the compiler wouldn't even find the C++ standard library! (but this is probably beside the point)

So the question is.. what else do I need to check in order to have the programme find the files I'm trying to open?

NOTE: the backbone of the project is written in C++, and I'm only using Cocoa in order to be able to dram images on the screen, so if anyone has a better approach to including graphics in a C++ project I'm all ears.

Thanks for reading

EDIT: I'm using Xcode 12.4 and Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: You want to learn what the current working directory is and how it can differ from the exe or the source file location. You can start from here [How to get the current directory in a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program)

Comment: Do you run the app from Xcode in debug mode? Is the app sandboxed? Does your app have permission to read the file?

Comment: @S.M. I will check this out thanks!

Comment: @Willeke Yes I am running the debug mode for now. Yes, it has permission to read files. Is it sandboxed? I will take a look at that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa apps do not work with files the same way as command-line C++ apps. Cocoa apps create an app bundle, which is where the files you want to read should be. If you have files you want to read in a Cocoa app, add them to the project. When you add the files to the project, they will get copied to the app bundle. Make sure they are in the app target's Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

[image]

Use the methods in the `Bundle` class to locate the files instead of `fopen`. The following Swift code locates a file named "MyFile.txt" in the main app bundle:

```
let mainBundle = Bundle.main
let fileURL = mainBundle.url(forResource: "MyFile", withExtension: "txt")
```

Comment: Mark. Thanks for your reply. Your explanation makes a lot of sense, since I'm getting this problem only with Cocoa apps. The code you posted is Swift though, and I'm working with Objective-C. I found this suggestion on a similar thread: 'NSString *myFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"subjects" ofType:@"plist"];'. With this I can get const char* with the file path. Reading the file path I obtained I can confirm that your suggestion was right, the file is located in an absolutely different place in Cocoa apps.. so thanks again, it works now.