# Path to the symlink

Tags: c, linux, symlink

I'm working on a program that prints info about a file in linux. I need a way to handle link files `(S_ISLNK(buf->st_mode))`, so that the program prints both the path of symlink and the file it points to. I already figured out the second part, but don't know how to do the first one although it seems easier. I run the program with a filename as a parameter, then the function that prints the stats has `struct stat buf` and `char *fname` as arguments. For the path to the file that symlink points to i used `realpath(fname, NULL)` as %s in printf. I tried to get the path of symlink using readlink but got the path to the file the symlink points to instead. The final code should look like:

```
printf("Path: %s\n", *char array or function that stores the path*);

printf("Points to: %s\n", realpath(fname, NULL));
```

Tried this:

```
char path[512];
readlink(fname, path, sizeof(path));
printf("Path: %s\n", path);
```

Does anyone know how I might go about this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not describe what you did, but show it. Provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. Also: "But didn't get it" isn't exactly a very useful statement. What did you get instead? Wrong path? An error message? Nothing?

Comment: [`getcwd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298510/how-to-get-the-current-directory-in-a-c-program) (or whatever directory you're currently statting) plus name of the symlink?

Comment: Actually it may work. I taught the exercise didn't specify the location of the file, but when I look at it now it says the file has to be in the same directory as the program. Thanks @yano

Comment: Note that `readlink` does not add a null terminator to the buffer, but returns the number of bytes placed in the buffer, or -1 on error.

Comment: @Hunes Please [edit] your question to add information instead of using comments for this purpose. Note that "the same directory as the program"  is not necessarily the "current working directory". You can run the program in different ways, e.g. `cd /location/of/the/program` `./yourprogram file_to_process` or `cd /some/other/directory` `/location/of/the/program/yourprogram file_to_process` and also specify a file name argument in different ways, e.g. `/location/of/the/program/yourprogram /path/to/file_to_process`

Comment: If the filename contains a `/` you could use `realpath` on everything up to the final `/`, then append the filename. If the filename does not contain a `/` use `getcwd`, or use `realpath` on the result of `getcwd`, then append the filename.

Comment: Are you looking to print the absolute pathname for the symlink and the path that it points at?  If so, you can tell whether the path is absolute by looking at the first character — if it is a `/`, the name is already absolute; otherwise, it is relative and one version of the absolute name can be gained by prefixing the result of `getcwd()` and a slash to the given name.  That's not great if the given name is `../../somewhere/somefile`, but it is possible to clean that up.  Consider whether `realpath(".", path)` can help — it does not require the given name to contain a `/`.